# Collection Framework & Data Structures

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, logic

I recently faced some technical interviews, the questions were:

> Q.1 Two Strings are given "Hello" & "World". Print Unique 
>       Characters Present in first and not in the second string
>
> OUTPUT: `He`.

**My Answer:** Compare each character of one string to with every other character of second, not optimal at all (**wrong**, obviously).

> Q.2 `ABCABBABCAB, OUTPUT:`4A5B2C`, (basically count occurrence of each character)
>           do this in one pass, not multiple traversal in string, there where other
>           Again do this in optimal way.

Similarly, there where few other question too..

Question which arises at core to me is:

- Which data structure from collection framework will help me to handle such scenarios in most optimum way; and
- Which particular data structure from Java Collection Framework to be used when and why?

Also, If there are books for such topics, do tell

***Any Help-Books, References and Links will be of great help in learning and understanding.***

**IMPORTANT: I need real time scenarios, where which the data structure is implemented**

I have studied, Collection API, not throughly, but a summarised idea of hierachy and major data structure classes. i know how to use them, but where and why exactly use them eludes me?

Comment: Q1: Set - Q2: Map. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html

Comment: Q1 has been asked here on SO before. Can't find the link right now, but I saw it a few weeks ago.

Comment: If you are really cool and know the range of your characters (e.G. ASCII) you can setup a int array for every possible character and count it at the index, afterwards just print those counts (greater than zero for example).

Comment: @ThomasJungblut creating array would consume space in memory, only few characters would be used and rest will only occupy space, not optimal, space wise

Comment: @AkhilJain if you care about optimizing for space, you are probably optimizing in the wrong direction. 128 ASCII characters don't consume that much memory, opposed to a hashset with character objects. If you can cut down the space to plain alphabet A-Z you are probably way more efficient than anything else (space&time).

Comment: @ThomasJungblut that's what they're usually expecting in String based interview question, that you deal with chars

Comment: @kolossus it's not only with Strings, it can be anything e.G. an integer array. The lesson learned is that you should know what options you have and what is more efficient in what case. If you're not sure in what case you are, simply ask until you have all the edge constants needed to make a decision. That's the job of an engineer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class G {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new G().printCharacterCount("ABCABBABCAB");
    System.out.println();
    new G().printUniqueCharacters("Hello", "world");
}

void printUniqueCharacters(String a, String b) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        set.add(a.charAt(i));

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
        set.remove(b.charAt(i));

    for (Character c : set)
        System.out.print(c);
}

void printCharacterCount(String a) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        char c = a.charAt(i);
        if(!map.containsKey(c))
            map.put(c, 0);

        map.put(c, map.get(c) +1);
    }

    for(char c : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.print(map.get(c) + "" + c);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton man,printCharacterCount() is spot on ,buttraversing through each array to full length in printUniqueCharacters() will be less efficient

Comment: @AkhilJain There is no way you can answer Q1 without reading both strings in full.

Answer (score 1):

Example of algorithm you could use.

Q1.

- put all the letters of String1 in a set (which only keeps unique entries)
- remove all the letters of String2 from the set
- your set now contains the unique letters of String1 which were not in String2

Q2.

- store the number of occurrence of the letters in a `Map<Character, Integer>`
- if a letter is not in the map, the count is 1
- if a letter is already in the map, the count needs to be incremented

> I know how to use them, but where and why exactly use them eludes me?

By trying to solve that kind of puzzle on your own ;-)

Comment: removing character is slow process,consumes more cycles, guess so

Comment: @AkhilJain What do you mean? The `remove` method of a `HashSet` runs in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Character> set1=new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject("Hello".toCharArray())));
Set<Character> set2=new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject("World".toCharArray())));
set1.removeAll(set2);
System.out.println(set1);
```

Using apache [ArrayUtils.toObject(char[] array)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28char%5B%5D%29) .You could write a util method instead.

Answer (score 0):

**For #1 :**

```
    String one = "Hello";
    String two = "World";
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
        set.add(one.charAt(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < two.length(); i++) {
        set.remove(two.charAt(i));
    }

    for (char ch : set) {
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
```

**For #2 :**

```
    String str = YourInput;
    int[] array = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        array[ch - 'A']++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println(array[i] + (char) (i + 'A'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Hello";
    String s2 = "World";

    List<Character> list1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    List<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(char c : s1.toCharArray()){
        if(!list1.contains(c)){
            list1.add(c);
        }
    }
    for(char c : s2.toCharArray()){
        if(!list2.contains(c)){
            list2.add(c);
        }
    }
    List<Character> uniqueList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (Character character1 : list1) {
        boolean unique = true;
        for (Character character2 : list2) {
            if(character1.equals(character2)){
                unique = false;
            }
        }
        if(unique){
            uniqueList.add(character1);
        }
    }
    for (Character character : uniqueList) {
        System.out.print(character);
    }
}
```